# Why Cloudflare keeps complaining that "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page"?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, cloudflare

I'm using this stack:

- C#
- Selenium
- ChromeDriver

And I want to automate a page protected by Cloudflare. I won't violate any guidelines of that site. I just want to automate some procedures that our employees want to do. Usually once each minute or two.

However, this site is protected by Cloudflare's DDoS prevention, and while I can go to that site in a normal Chrome browser by solving captcha, for some weird reason in an automated Chrome it keeps reloading the same Cloudflare page complaining that:

[image]

What I see in the UI is **Checking your browser before accessing ...**. But when I look into DevTools and Network tab, I see the response code 503 and the message **Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page**.

The point is, I checked and JavaScript is already enabled. This is how I made sure:

- Chrome settings
- Searching for JavaScript (which is located in **Site settings** in Chrome 85.0.4183.121)
- Scrolled down to find JavaScript, clicked on it and made sure it's on (as in the image below)

[image]

What should I do? How can I fix this?